Changing fields during PhD
I’m three months into a PhD (in the UK) at a professional school exploring AI Ethics. My undergraduate background is in Philosophy and I jumped directly into my PhD (~3 years with no taught elements). I’ve not done any work on AI before, and am feeling quite overwhelmed with the underlying mathematics (eg: algorithmic fairness literature, working of deep learning systems etc). My interests and strengths are largely in qualitative research, I don’t have much of a quantitative background, and I feel like I’m trying to tip toe around the quantitative literature to find a question that I could actually attempt to answer. I also have strong interest in other areas of philosophy (especially aesthetics, epistemology and the philosophy of art) and am now wondering if I would have been better off having applied for a PhD within a Philosophy department instead, where I could have focused theoretical rather than applied philosophy. Would dropping out of my current program with an Mres in a year work against me in applying to other PhD programs in Philosophy in the UK/US? Would I be better off trying to endure the three years, getting a PhD and then applying to jobs in a philosophy department and then working on a different topic (is that practical given the competition for jobs in philosophy)? I applied to this PhD because I enjoyed doing philosophy, and had some experience with applied philosophy projects (business and environmental ethics) that I had previously enjoyed, but I have now come to despise AI and can’t bring myself to care about my thesis question. I’ve been told that my job prospects will be much better with a qualification in AI Ethics than in theoretical philosophy, but I’m scared I won’t have anything meaningful to contribute here and can’t really imagine working in AI ethics in the long term at this point…

To "endure the three years" does not sound very tempting, especially because you say I "can’t bring myself to care about my thesis question" and "I’m scared I won’t have anything meaningful to contribute". It is not given that you will get the degree after three years. Do you have any support and guidance by a person you trust and can discuss this with in sufficient detail? What about your scientific advisor?

From what you write, I think you have made a decision but just don't want to admit it yet, but it is hard to see a reason to stay. You are just beginning on this path and it would be difficult as you note. You also suggest it would be unsatisfying. Maybe you should look at all your options and see what is better.
Normally I wouldn't answer such a personal question, but you may just need a bit of a kick. Talk to your current advisor before you jump, however.
Changing institutions comes with a time cost, but you might be able to spend that time productively if you don't immediately quit while looking.
You don't get do-overs in life. Choose something that you truly want.
You can always take up AI and its philosophical implications later. The field is in flux at the moment. Too much hype. Too much promotion by commercial interests.
Note that you don't need a masters for US doctoral applications. And quitting with a masters won't hurt you, but in many places you would still need to do the necessary prep for comprehensive exams, assuming they are part of a program. That could add to the time required.

I'm from a highly multidisciplinary lab. Most of the PhD students in my lab work on ethics-related research. However, not all of them code or work directly with AI's mathematical background. One of the nice things about this era of AI we are currently leaving is that not all work has to be directly linked to these aspects. Some of the students have even finished their PhD without coding a single line of code, which shows how diverse PhD in Computer Science has become.
You mentioned that you went straight for a PhD from your bachelor's. That is fine, but one thing that I realised, talking to many students in the same scenario as you, is that as you progress in academia, you understand that knowing everything in your field is impossible. If you are really interested in philosophy, there are plenty of CS researchers that do just that.
I would suggest you take a broader look at the field and try to find topics you are interested in. Afterwards, you should read literature reviews for those problems and see how you can contribute. It is important to remember that the first AI paper from Turing was published in a psychology journal, so there is no reason to be overwhelmed by all the possible things out there.
Additionally, having researched ethics in AI, I see that the field is mostly looking for qualitative research. Many papers about fairness and ethics use only quantitative metrics that don't mean what the authors think they mean. In the past few conferences I attended, there were many calls to recruit people outside of Computer Science into AI research.
Lastly, don't push it if you don't think that is the game for you. Three years is a long time to swallow and get through. I'd consider talking to my supervisor to find a compromise, and if that doesn't work, I'd try to find new positions or even a supervisor.
Best of luck!
